# Big data indexing advice on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I am about to import around 500 million rows of telemetry data into SQL Server 2008 R2, and I want to make sure I get the indexing/schema right to allow for fast searches of the data.  I've been working with databases for a while but nothing on this scale.  I'm hoping I can describe my data and the application, and someone can advise me on a good strategy for indexing it.

The data is instrument readings from a data collection system, and has 3 columns: SentTime (datetime2(3)), Topic (nvarchar(255), and Value(float).  The SentTime precision is to the millisecond, and is NOT unique.  There are around 400 distinct Topics (ex: "Voltage1", "PumpPressure", etc) in the data, and my plan was to break out the data into about 30 tables, each with 10-15 columns, grouped into logical groupings like Voltages, Pressures, Temperatures, etc, each with their own SentTime column.

A typical search will be to retrieve various Values (could be across several tables) for a given time range.  Another possible search will be to retrieve all times/values for a given value range and topic.  The user interface will show coarse graphs of the data, to allow the user to find the interesting data and export it to Excel or CSV.

My main question is, if I add an index based on SentTime alone, will that speed searches for a given time range?  Would it be better to make a composite index on time and value, since the time is not unique? Any point in adding a unique primary key? Is there any other overall strategy or schema I should be looking at for this application?

Another note, I will not be inserting any data once the import is done, so no need to worry about the insertion overhead of indexes.

Comment: what version of SQL Server? Enterprise or Standard?

Comment: Enterprise. We will also soon be moving to 2012, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yakshemash ! Long ago, I read a bit about `partitioning tables` in SQL server. See if that works for you. Here is a nice, info-rich link - http://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources/ Please let us know if this is helpful or not. Chenqui.

Comment: One corollary question: when I tried to add an index to an existing table of ~ 1 million rows, it said it may take a long time, then failed with a timeout.  Is it really impossible to add an index to a large table?  At this point I can afford to plan ahead, but in general that seems very limiting if you can't add an index to a large table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'll be doing a lot of range searches over the SentTime column. In that case, I would create a clustered index on SentTime; with the nonclustered index there would be the overhead of lookups (to retrieve additional data). It is not important that SentTime is not unique, engine will add an uniquifier to it.

Does the Topic column have to be nvarchar; why not a varchar?

My relational self will punish me for this, but it seems that you don't need an additional PK. The data **is** read-only, right?

One more thought: check the [sparse columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx) feature, it seems that it would be a perfect fit in your scenario. There could be a large number of sparse columns (up to 10.000 if I'm not mistaken), they can be grouped and manipulated as XML, and the main point is that NULLs are almost free storage-wise.

Comment: As to your comment on whether to add something else for a PK, I would. The reason being is that because your clustering key is not unique, the engine is going to add a uniquifier so that it can get down to an individual row. So you may as well be explicit about it because you're going to be paying the cost in terms of storage either way.

Comment: Thanks dean for your input, very informative.  The Topic does not need to be nvarchar, could be varchar, I suppose this would save some storage space.  The data is indeed read-only.  I'm not sure about the motivation for the sparse columns, I'm not sure why I would need a lot of null entries.  To Ben -> I can see your reasoning, maybe I'll try both ways and see what the storage hit is for each method.  Thanks to all.

Comment: RE sparse cols, I as under impression that for any given SentTime there will be only a couple of values actually available. Feel free to disregard that part if it isn't so.